# Filter using Nested Struct Field

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
|-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- keyNote: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- note: string (nullable = true)
```

With the example structure above, how would I select the note field under the structs data and keyNote?

I need to filter with two different data frames and can not seem to be able to select a nested field. I am using **Spark 1.6.2** where the left anti isn't available so I used the following filter. Below are two ways I have tried.

```
val dataFrame = esData.join(broadcastDataFrame, esData.select(esData.col("data.keyNote")).col("note") !== broadcastDataFrame("id")) 

Error: Cannot resolve column name "note" among (keyNote)


val dataFrame = esData.join(broadcastDataFrame, esData.select(esData.col("data.keyNote.*")).col("note") !== broadcastDataFrame("id")) 

Error: No such struct field * in key, note


val dataFrame = esData.join(broadcastDataFrame, esData("data.keyNote.note") !== broadcastDataFrame("id")) 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "note" does not exist.(..)


val dataFrame = esData.join(broadcastDataFrame, esData.select($"data.keyNote.note").col("note") !== broadcastDataFrame("id")) 

Error: resolved attribute(s) note#9 missing from data#1,id#3 in operator !Join Inner, Some(NOT (note#9 = id#3))
```

The dataFrame used is created from Elastic Search (artifact: **elastic-spark-13_2.10, Version:5.1.1**)

```
val dataFrameES = context.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
   .options(Map("es.read.field.exclude" ->
    "<Excluding All the fields except those I need>"))
   .load("<Index>/<Type>")
```

Now I attempted to use the `es.read.field.include` but nothing I tried would be able to retrieve the nested items except for excluding everything else. I tried to include the following; data, data.keyNote, data.keyNote.key, and every permutation plus wildcard of * after each. I am not sure if this is a spark thing or an elastic search thing.

I thought it was the schema being read wrong until I excluded all the unwanted fields and successfully retrieved the ones I wanted.

I think now that it is the join because I am able to grab that field with no errors in a filter like so;

```
 esData.filter(esData("data.keyNote.key").equalTo("x"))
```

I just continue to get errors when I try to complete the join above, which is required being I have two data sets. When I do run the filter above right after creating the elastic search data frame is takes far longer than running a curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
df1.join(df2, df1("x.y.z") !== df2("v"))
```

or

```
df1.join(df).where(df1("x.y.z") !== df2("v")
```

Full example

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val esData = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(Seq(
  """{"data": {"keyNote": {"key":   "foo", "note": "bar"}}}""")))

val broadcastDataFrame = Seq((1L, "foo"), (2L, "bar")).toDF("n", "id")

esData.join(
  broadcastDataFrame, esData("data.keyNote.note") !== broadcastDataFrame("id")
).show

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+-----------+---+---+
|       data|  n| id|
+-----------+---+---+
|[[foo,bar]]|  1|foo|
+-----------+---+---+

esData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [data: struct<keyNote:struct<key:string,note:string>>]
broadcastDataFrame: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [n: bigint, id: string]
```

If you want `antijoin` it is better to use outer join and filter out `nulls`.